# Cancel and refund ALL google play subscriptions

Tags: google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-play-developer-api

We have an app in the Google Play Store that we will no longer support in the future.

Users were able to buy subscriptions for the app's content.

We want to cancel all running subscriptions and refund the users.

The Google Play Developer Api offers the [revoke](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/revoke) method that expects the details (subscription id, token) for a single subscription and will cancel & refund that subscription.

We would have to do that for a couple of thousands of users (probably via a script).

Is there a better way to revoke all subscriptions? 
Has someone probably faced a similar scenario?

Comment: @Albert Renshaw I didn't find any possibility to revoke all subscriptions at once. 
I ended up writing a little Kotlin program that cancelled one after the other, took about 1-2 hours iirc to be done with a couple of thousand subscriptions. 
I can share that with you if you're facing a similar task.

Comment: Yeah can you stick that up on github and post a link here as an answer, I think that would help a lot of people

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Will do first thing on Monday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not find a method of revoking all subscriptions at once so I wrote a little program that reads subscription data from a file and revokes them, one after another. 
You can check it out here: https://github.com/asco33/reimburser